# SSH connection refused for Google App Engine VM instance

Tags: google-app-engine, ssh, google-cloud-platform

I have deployed a flask application on a google app engine VM instance. Everything was going fine, I was editing my code locally, then deploying and debugging by looking at the logs, but after my last deployment, I am seeing the following error when I try to open the app in a browser:

> Error: Server Error
>
> The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
>
> Please try again in 30 seconds.

Also, I am now unable to ssh into my App engine VM instance. Whenever I try to ssh, I get the following error:

> port 22: Connection refused

(I was able to ssh into this VM earlier).

Now, I have a VPC network, which has the default firewall rules for allowing ssh ports. There is a section in the cloud platform dashboard where I can create firewall rules for App engine, but it is only for allowing IP addresses, and not ports (regardless, I have added my IP address in this firewall rule).

I also get the same error when I try to SSH through the web cloud platform  dashboard.

Most of the related pages on StackOverflow I found about this error are
people not being able to SSH into **compute engine** VMs. I'm  stuck and have no idea what to do to be able to SSH into my **App Engine** VM.

I am also not seeing any logs when I use the "gcloud app logs read" command.

Edit: Following are my App Engine firewall rules :

[image]

Following are the firewall rules for my VPC network:

[image]

Comment: Can you go to https://console.cloud.google.com/ and see if you can ssh in from there? See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/debugging-an-instance

Comment: It sounds like it might be a firewall problem though. Are you sure you whitelisted your IP rather than block it? Maybe a conflicting rule with higher priority?

Comment: Going to App Engine → Versions there is a list with last deployed versions. Can you access the logs selecting Tools → Logs? Try also to stop the current deployment and start an old one that you know was working, just to see if it still works. Firewall rules look fine to me but you can define the port in them in step 11 following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a firewall problem if you can't `ssh` in from the [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/). Can you post your firewall rules?

Comment: I have now posted the firewall rules in my question.

Comment: Thanks, those look completely normal. Can you stop/delete the instance and start over? I was thinking that maybe you've set the wrong project in the shell, but you said you can't ssh from the web interface either.

Comment: @Karan, I flagged your question:
Last image posted in last edition contains security issues: project name + IP addresses. 
It contains also personal information: tabs + folders in chrome.
Try to add "black bands" to cover sensitive information, and cut the images.